# Texture paint look different in object mode and on render

Tags: rendering, texture-painting

In blender i have a fish object that i paint with texture paint, in texture paint mode and object mode, the fish look like this :
[image]

When i try to render the object, it look like this:
[image]

it looks like the line in the fish is different, the one after render look like a bit jittery
Do anybody know how to fix this issue

Comment: pls provide blend file to check it out

Comment: You are using a subsurf modifier in render. Turn it on for the viewport as well and try different UV Smooth options.